# How is the defStyleAttrs parameter used in obtainStyledAttributes

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am trying to create a custom compound view (subclassed out of relativelayout) on android and am trying to specify default styles. I can accomplish this, but I want to know what the defStyleAttr parameter is used for, and how to use it.

I have run into this method context.obtainStyledAttributes (AttributeSet set, int[] attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes).

I understand that:

- `AttributeSet set` I will get from the view's constructor if
  inflating from XML,
- `int[] attrs` will be the key values for any
  custom view fields I may have created,
- `int defStyleRes` will be a
  default style that I can provide, which is defined as a style
  resource.

However, I can't figure out how to use `int defStyleAttr` parameter. I've read the documentation and have provided an attr resource like this:

```
<declare-styleable name="BMTheme">
        <attr name="BMButtonStyle" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

and then in my themes resource file I have this:

```
<style name="Theme.Custom" parent="@android:style/Theme">
    <item name="BMButtonStyle">@style/BMButton</item>
</style>
```

which in turn references this style:

```
<style name="BMButton">
    <item name="text">some string</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
</style>
```

In code, when I pass in 0 for `defStyleAttr` and the style resource id for `defStyleRes`, I successfully get the default values that I defined in my BMButton style:

```
TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.RightArrowButton, 0, R.style.BMButton);
```

However when I pass in the attr resource id for BMButtonStyle(which in turn references the BMButton style) for `defStyleAttr`, and 0 for `defStyleRes` then I do not get the values I specified in the style.

```
TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.RightArrowButton, R.attr.BMButtonStyle, 0);
```

Please let me know if I am using the `defStyleAttr` parameter the wrong way, and if anyone knows, why is there a need for both a `defStyleAttr` and a `defStyleRes` parameter when it seems like just a `defStyleRes` will suffice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out where I was going wrong after reading this post:
[Creating default style with custom attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072153/creating-default-style-with-custom-attributes)

Basically, in order to use the `defStyleAttr` parameter, my project needed to set my custom theme defined theme in the manifest.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Custom" >
```